# How to use SignalR to display data from the database using google charts

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, google-visualization, signalr

I have read a lot of data about how to use SignalR to display data from the database using google charts, but I still have no idea about it .
Now I can make a google charts but it is hardcode, I have seen the Microsoft sample of SignalR StockTickR, I think I can revise the random to a real database.

```
 private bool TryUpdateStockPrice(Stock stock)
    {
        // Randomly choose whether to udpate this stock or not
        var r = _updateOrNotRandom.NextDouble();
        if (r > 0.1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Update the stock price by a random factor of the range percent
        var random = new Random((int)Math.Floor(stock.Price));
        var percentChange = random.NextDouble() * _rangePercent;
        var pos = random.NextDouble() > 0.51;
        var change = Math.Round(stock.Price * (decimal)percentChange, 2);
        change = pos ? change : -change;

        stock.Price += change;
        return true;
    }
```

Can someone give me some advice?